# handling php function that shutdown the system in a button by onclick event

Tags: javascript, php, html

A php function to shutdown my pc is not handled in a button by onclick event handler. On refreshing my page the pc warns about a shutdown before i can click the button which should invoke the event handler.

Am using windows 10 and i have a .bat file which works fine. Event in php after executing the .bat file it is shutting the pc as expected.The problem is after setting a button element in html to listen to a click that it can shut the pc. on loading the page with the script and the html the pc warns shutting down  which is unexpected as no click on the button has been made.

```
<?php
function sysShut(){
 try{ 
    echo 'Computer shutdown on the way <br/>';

    ob_start();
    exec("systemshutdown.bat"); 
    ob_end_clean();
    //echo 'not a shame <br/>';
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e.getMessage();
 }  
}
?>

<button id="btn" onclick="<?php sysShut();?>" class="btn btn-warning">
<img src="images/shutdownicon.jpeg"  alt="shutdownicon.png" title="PC 
   Shutdown"/>
</button>
```

the expectation is that the script in .bat file should run only after clicking the button

Comment: You can't run PHP code client side. That code is ran when the server is sending the page to the browser. Place your shutdown script in a separate php file, and request that file with `XMLHTTPRequest` or JQuery.ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call a PHP function by using HTML `onclick` attribute. You can do this only for JavaScript.

The reason why the function is executed always is because here

```
<button id="btn" onclick="<?php sysShut();?>" class="btn btn-warning">
```

you are actually calling the php function without any condition and this is executed when you load the page.

To achieve your goal, you should put the PHP script which shuts down your computer in another page, called for example `shutdown.php`:

```
<?php
function sysShut(){
 try{ 
    echo 'Computer shutdown on the way <br/>';

    ob_start();
    exec("systemshutdown.bat"); 
    ob_end_clean();
    //echo 'not a shame <br/>';
 }
 catch(Exception $e){
    echo $e.getMessage();
 }  
}

sysShut();
?>
```

And then do:

```
<html><body>
<button id="btn" onclick="location.href = 'shutdown.php';" class="btn btn-warning">
</body></html>
```